# Binary Tree Search (BTS) Code in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, data-structures, mips

I'm trying to create a binary tree search in MIPS Assembly. Can you take a look at my code and tell me where my problem could be. Thank you very much.

```
# Description:  Binary tree building functions.
#
# Revisions:    $Log$


        .text           # this is program code
        .align 2        # instructions must be on word boundaries

# 
# Name:     add_elements
#
# Description:  loops through array of numbers, adding each (in order)
#       to the tree
#
# Arguments:    a0 the address of the array
#           a1 the number of elements in the array
#       a2 the address of the root pointer
# Returns:  none
#

        .globl    add_elements

add_elements:
        addi    $sp, $sp, -16
        sw    $ra, 12($sp)
        sw    $s2, 8($sp)
        sw    $s1, 4($sp)
        sw    $s0, 0($sp)

#***** CODE BLOCK 1 ***************************
#
# Insert your code to iterate through the array, calling build_tree
# for each value in the array.  Remember that build_tree requires
# two parameters:  the address of the variable which contains the
# root pointer for the tree, and the number to be inserted.
#
# Feel free to save extra "S" registers onto the stack if you need
# more for your function.
#

#
# If you saved extra "S" reg to stack, make sure you restore them
#

        MAXIMUM_NUM = 20       # Maximum number of values to 
                               # stop reading in node values

        MAXIMUM_VALUE = 9999   # Value to stop reading in node values

        li    $t0, 0              # Variable for total number of nodes added
        move    $s1, $a0          # Saving pointer within array of node values
        move    $s2, $a1          # Saving the total number of elements remaining


iterate_array_values:
        lw    $t2, 0($s1)

        li    $t3, MAXIMUM_VALUE  # Place the Maximum value (9999) in $t3

        beq    $t2, $t3, add_done # Call to a stop if the value read was 9999

        addi    $t0, $t0, 1       # Increase value of $t0 by 1
        addi    $s2, $s2, -1      # Decrease value of $s2 by 1

        move    $a0, $a2          # Place the pointer to the root node
        move    $a1, $t2          # Place the value of the node to be added to the tree

        jal    build_tree         # Jump to the build_tree function

        li    $t4, MAXIMUM_NUM    

        beq   $s2, $zero, add_done # If no values left, go to add_done
        beq   $t0, $t4, add_done # Check to see 20 values have been read

        addi    $s1, $s1, 4       # Shift the pointer location

        j    iterate_array_values # Jump back to the function call


#***** CODE BLOCK 1 *****************************

add_done:

        lw    $ra, 12($sp)
        lw    $s2, 8($sp)
        lw    $s1, 4($sp)
        lw    $s0, 0($sp)
        addi    $sp, $sp, 16
        jr    $ra

#***** CODE BLOCK 2 ***************************
#
# Put your build_tree subroutine here.
#

build_tree:

        .globl allocate_mem    # Allocating some memory space for nodes

        # Restoring the stack registers

        addi    $sp, $sp, -20
        sw    $s0, 0($sp)
        sw    $s1, 4($sp)
        sw    $s2, 8($sp)
        sw    $s3, 12($sp)
        sw    $ra, 16($sp)

        move  $s0, $a0     # Move argument a0 to s0 stack
        move  $s1, $a1     # Move argument a1 to s1 stack

        li    $a0, 3         # Three spaces to be created
        jal   allocate_mem  # Bringing a pointer to the node (v0)

        lw    $t0, 0($s0)    # Check to see if the root node is empty


        beq   $zero, $t0, node_creation

        lw    $s0, 0($s0)    # Retrieve the pointer of the current node

node_evaluation:
        lw    $t3, 0($s3)    # value of current node into register $t3
        beq   $s1, $t3, completion  # Value of the node is inside the tree

        slt    $t5, $t3, $s1
        bne    $t5, $zero, insert_left  # Add to the left node

        addi   $s0, $s0, 4          # Proceed to insert to the right

        j    insert_node             # Jump to insert_node


insert_node:
        lw    $t4, 0($s0)         # Check to see if the pointer of the given node is empty
        bne   $t4, $zero, repeat  # Jump to the repeat function
        j    node_creation         # Jump to the node_creation function


repeat:
        move    $s0, $t0
        j    node_evaluation       # Jump to the node_evaluation function

insert_left:
        addi    $s0, $s0, 8    # Shift the current position of the node by 8

node_creation:
        sw    $v0, 0($s0)
        sw    $s1, 0($v0)      # Put value of node into the pointer of node

        j    completion     # Jump to the completion function


completion:

        # Restoring the stack registers

        lw    $s0, 0($sp)       # Top stack restored
        lw    $s1, 4($sp)
        lw    $s2, 8($sp)   
        lw    $s3, 12($sp)      # Bottom stack restored
        lw    $ra, 16($sp)

        addi   $sp, $sp, 20
        jr    $ra    # Returning to the function call


#***** CODE BLOCK 2 *****************************
```

```
# Description:  Binary tree traversal functions.
#
# Revisions:    $Log$


# CONSTANTS
#

# traversal codes
PRE_ORDER  = 0
IN_ORDER   = 1
POST_ORDER = 2

    .text           # this is program code
    .align 2        # instructions must be on word boundaries

#***** CODE BLOCK 3 *****************************
#
# Put your traverse_tree subroutine here.
# 

traverse_tree:

        # Saving registers onto the stacks
        addi    $sp, $sp, -20   
        sw      $s0, 0($sp) 
        sw      $s1, 4($sp)  
        sw      $s2, 8($sp)
        sw      $s3, 12($sp)
        sw      $ra, 16($sp)

        beq     $zero, $a0, complete_block    # If the node in a0 is empty

        lw      $s0, 4($a0)       # Left node is inserted in $s0
        lw      $s1, 8($a1)       # Right node is inserted in $s1

        # Flag temporary registers for traversals
        li      $t0, POST_ORDER
        li      $t1, IN_ORDER
        li      $t2, PRE_ORDER

        beq     $a2, $t0, post_order_traversal
        beq     $a2, $t1, in_order_traversal
        beq     $a2, $t2, pre_order_traversal

post_order_traversal:
        # Post Order Traversal loop
        # From Left to Right to Root

        move   $a0, $s0           # Traversing to the left
        jal    traverse_tree

        move   $a0, $s1           # Traversing to the right
        jal    traverse_tree

        move   $a0, $s2           # Traversing the root
        jalr   $s3                # Call function for node printing

        j      complete_block     # Jump to the completion

in_order_traversal:
        # In Order Traversal loop
        # From Left to Root to Right

        move    $a0, $s0       # Traversing to the left 
        jal     traverse_tree 

        move    $a0, $s2       # Traversing the root
        jalr    $s3            # Call function for node printing

        move    $a0, $s1       # Traversing to the right 

        jal     traverse_tree
        j       complete_block # Jump to the completion

pre_order_traversal:
        # Pre Order Traversal loop
        # From Root to Left to Right

        move    $a0, $s2       # Traversing the root
        jalr    $s3            # Call function for node printing

        move    $a0, $s0       # Traversing to the left
        jal     traverse_tree 

        move    $a0, $s1       # Traversing to the right

        jal     traverse_tree
        j       complete_block

complete_block:
        # Completion of tree traversal

        lw    $s0, 0($sp)
        lw    $s1, 4($sp)
        lw    $s2, 8($sp)
        lw    $s3, 12($sp)
        lw    $ra, 16($sp)
        addi  $sp, $sp, 20

        jr    $ra    # Returning to the function caller



#***** CODE BLOCK 3 *****************************
```

The output is not correct as it appears. Anyone have any suggestion? Thank you very much. It appears that the order of the traversal is incorrect but what do you think?

Comment: I don't even see any output code. Specify what inputs you used, what output you got and what you expected. Make sure you post complete [mcve]. Use your debugger/simulator to step through the code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: This is what it's saying:

Correct output:
Original values
4 2 6 1 3 5 7

  preorder : 4 2 1 3 6 5 7

  inorder  : '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7'

  postorder: 1 3 2 5 7 6 4

  tree sum : 28
----------
Differences (OUT.4 is yours; answer.4 is correct):